# How to use ngTagsInput in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

How to create multiple input field dynamically like stack overflow Tags field ?

### Component.html

```
<form name="form"  (ngSubmit)="keySkillRequest()">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName"> Key Skills:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="skills" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
     </div>

     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you must need something to click in order to create new filed, right?

Comment: ya right only but using key press event

Answer (score 2):

Did you think of using an npm package instead of implementing it by yourself?

[PrimeNg - autocomplete (multiple)](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/autocomplete) is a good solution for you.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/autocomplete

Comment: thanks @oCcSking I changed the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code might be it will help full for you.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-skill',
  styles: ['div { border: 1px solid #ccc}'],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="skillForm" (ngSubmit)="keySkillRequest(skillForm.value)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let skill of tagList">
     <a href="#" > {{skill}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Skill" formControlName="name"> <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </div>
  </div>
</form>`,
})

export class SkillComponent {
  public skillForm: FormGroup;
  tagList: any = [];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.skillForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  keySkillRequest(val) {
    this.tagList.push(val.name);
    this.skillForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: ya this is right only but i want different types like stack overflow tags input field(go to the ASK Questions  there is a tags field)

Comment: @lpd I have altered my answer please have look once again.